# HTML/CSS Table with rounded corners and rows dividers?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to make an HTML table with **rounded corners** and **rows dividers**.

However, it looks like they are mutually exclusive:

- rows dividers `tr {border-bottom: 1px solid #000000}` require
  `border-collapse: collapse` to work
- table rounded corners `table { border-radius: 4px }` don't work with
  `border-collapse: collapse`

how can I achieve this?

Comment: so you want border to rows and border radius to table ? or border-radius to rows also ?

Comment: border radius just to the table; for the rows I would just like a straight line to divide them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the `table` inside a div, and give that div a `border-radius` plus `overflow:hidden`.

A `div` is a `block` element, so i used `display:table` on it to have the width of the table. But you can use `inline-block` or other.

See below

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.wrapper {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @DanieleB glad i could help. Cheers ! :D

Answer (score -2):

don't add the border radius to the table itself. try to wrap the table inside a div element, then add the border-radius to the div element.